# How do those who understand Noah's Flood to be a global flood explain what the carnivorous animals ate after disembarking?

Tags: genesis, flood-of-noah, literalism

How do those who understand Noah's Flood to be a global flood explain what the carnivorous animals ate after disembarking, if there were only 2 of all the other species left? Eating 1 would stop those species' reproductive lines, so what happened here?

Comment: Seafood was abundant

Comment: Is there any evidence that there were _any_ 'carnivorous' animals on the Ark ? (And omnivores are not 'carnivorous'.)

Comment: "*there were only 2 of all the other species left*" — Actually there were 14 of each kosher species. So we know that at least Noah and family could survive for a while.

Comment: https://answersingenesis.org/noahs-ark/feeding-carnivores-noahs-ark/

Comment: @Lige Yes, that might be the wisest response for those who hold to a literal account including a global flood. "We trust God's word, so this must be so. We don't know how it's so."

Comment: @NigelJ Good point - for part of the question, it doesn't really matter, as long as there was predation upon the other sorts of animals, whether the animal doing the hunting is an omnivore or carnivore.

Comment: "We don't know how it's so"... bah. Christians should not stop investigation because we don't have an answer. That's the exact sort of anti-science of which scoffers accuse Creationists. That's exactly opposite to how science *started*, when it was started *by Christians*. Scripture tells us to have a *reason* for our beliefs. Do we have all the answers? Of course not. What we *do* know coincides beautifully with Scripture, however.

Comment: @Matthew I'm not saying don't investigate. I'm saying admit when one doesn't have a clear answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably best answered by [this article](https://answersingenesis.org/noahs-ark/feeding-carnivores-noahs-ark/), but for the sake of having an Answer here...

First off, I want to take an aside to address a point that unbelievers often raise; namely, that there's no way Noah could take two of each of thousands of species of animal *and* have enough food for them.

That isn't what Scripture actually says, though it's easy to see where a layperson might be confused. There were not two of every *species* of animal on the Ark; there were two of every *kind* of animal. "Species" is a relatively recent, and very poorly defined delineation. Scripturally speaking, animals reproduce *according to their kind*. Lions and housecats can interbreed (at least through intermediaries), and are therefore the same [kind](https://creationwiki.org/Created_kind) (some Creation scientists like to use the term *baramin*). Same with wolves and dingoes, horses and zebras, and many others. Therefore, Noah only needed two of the *cat kind* (and likely those would have been closer to the size of servals than tigers). Conservative but realistic estimates place the number of *animals* (many of which were likely quite small) at less than ten thousand. Some calculations have estimated that the Ark could hold *hundreds* of thousands of animals the size of sheep (which are well above median size). Even with this latter figure likely assuming fairly crowded conditions with no food storage, it's easy to see that the problem is nowhere near as difficult as scoffers try to make it out to be. [This article](https://answersingenesis.org/noahs-ark/how-could-all-animals-fit-ark/) goes into further detail.

The above is not totally irrelevant to the original question. Having established that feeding the animals *on* the Ark was nowhere near so difficult as scoffers suppose, one immediate possible solution is that the Ark carried enough supplies to last for some time after. (Keep in mind that Noah et al were in the Ark for a little over a year; if, in that time, they used three quarters of their original supplies, the leftovers might still last for *months*.)

Another critical point is that most Creationists believe that no animals were created to be carnivorous. The ark was no opened until after a dove had brought back an olive branch, and subsequently left and not returned. This shows not only that plants were again growing, but suggests that the dove felt it could survive without relying on Noah to feed it. If we also suppose that the disembarking animals could still subsist, at least for a while, on a plant-based diet, we have substantially mitigated the food concerns. On top of that, one needs to bear in mind that *aquatic* animals were not wiped out.

The assumption that dozens of animals would immediately need to kill other *land* animals in order to survive is just that; an assumption. One should also keep in mind that it's hard to make a kill when there's perhaps only a hundred or so potential prey animals *in the entire world*.

On the other hand... the fossil record reveals any number of animals that are now extinct. While historic records of some of these persist until as recently as a few centuries ago, it may also be the case that some species *were* almost immediately killed off.

Comment: Thanks for the edification on my comments, they were certainly too flippant.  I've deleted them now.  My point remains that, even in the ideal scenario you have described, building a boat large enough to hold thousands of animals and their food, then feeding them, still seems pretty out of reach for Noah and company.  While it is certainly possible, I still imagine that a miraculous loaves-and-fishes event was more likely.  You've given me a lot of food for thought (pun unintended), though, so thanks for helping me to mull over the way I read about Noah.  :)

Comment: @Lige, if Noah only had a couple years (and no help), you might be right . Keep in mind, however, that Noah had as much as 120 *years* of warning, and may have had (older) family to help until shortly before the Flood started. You really ought to check out the Ark Encounter and/or related resources. Can we definitely say no miracles were involved? Of course not! But we have a 1:1 replica that suggests we don't *need* miracles, at least for the animal husbandry.

Comment: I just looked up the Ark Encounter, very interesting!  Thanks for the reference. :)